# add function onclick in json parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im trying to load article from json (its works) and add it link to fucntion, but when I add the a href tag with onclick function (for example - alert), the function doesn't work.

what am I missing?

```
$.getJSON(categoryAddr,function(data){
    json=data;
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $.each(json, function (i, value) {
        var list ="<a href='#' onclick='alert('hey!');'>"
        +"<h1>" + value.title + "</h1>" 
        + "<img src='" + value.image + "' alt=''/>"
        +"<h2>" + value.excerpt + "</h2></a>";
        $('.hold').append(list);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: look in your developer tools console for errors

Comment: check for errors when click on the link you are generating in the `each` loop

Comment: I mean when you click - there will be errors I'm almost positive

Comment: nothing happen when I click

Comment: `nothing happen when I click` that is given since there is a unescaped quote. Can you check for errors in console (Browser console) when you click?

Comment: Im working with TIZEN simulator and nothing shows up in the console.
maybe I didnt understand where to look

Comment: Also, try using `use strict` when handling JSON. Might help to uncover potential errors.

Comment: if you can't check on a browser console, then put a try catch block around your code and see if there are any errors

Comment: Try using double quotes around your function call. 

`onclick=\"alert('hey!')\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escaped double quotes around your JS

`var list ="<a href='#' onclick=\"alert('hey!');\">"`

Answer (score 3):

you need to escapq quotes inside the `alert`

change this line

```
var list ="<a href='#' onclick='alert('hey!');'>"
```

to

```
var list ="<a href='#' onclick='alert(\'hey!\');'>"
```

Comment: That is why i don't like inline handlers. better to go for delegated events.

Comment: @Jai that is true, but OP is asking `What am i missing` :)

Answer (score 0):

Define onclick event outside instead of defining it inline as shown below

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
     var json={title:'title1'};
    $.each(json, function (i, value) {   
        var list ="<a href='#' onclick=\"alert('hey!');\">"
        +"<h1>" + value + "</h1>" ;
        $('.hold').append(list);
        });      
    });
```

Fiidle : https://jsfiddle.net/9qes9u8u/

Updated Fiddle based upon @rzr answer

https://jsfiddle.net/t8o56g28/

Answer (score 0):

I would go for delegated events:

```
var list ="<a href='#' class='link'>"
```

Now you can use this script, and you don't need to have a nested doc ready block:

```
$.getJSON(categoryAddr,function(data){
    json=data;
    $.each(json, function (i, value) {
        var list ="<a href='#' data-id='" + value.id +"' class='link'>"
        +"<h1>" + value.title + "</h1>" 
        + "<img src='" + value.image + "' alt=''/>"
        +"<h2>" + value.excerpt + "</h2></a>";
        $('.hold').append(list);
    });  
});
```

This is delegated event on newly created anchor:

```
 $('.hold').on('click', '.link', function(){
    alert($(this).data("id"));
 });
```

Comment: tnx!
can I assign the alert var from json? for ex. alert(value.title)

Comment: Absolutely! But other way round like you can use `data-*` attribute to store it and alert it. Updating.